# R: how to add new column and fill with values conditional on other column (simple)

Tags: r, dataset

I know this question is incredibly simple and has already been answered - my issue is that I am a *complete* beginner to R (and I mean COMPLETE beginner), and all of the answers and explanations I have found pertaining to this query are complicated and require a greater depth of understanding of R than I currently have (and have time to learn).

I have a large csv dataset (500k+ rows of data), called 'overviewGenes', and I need to create a new column and fill each cell in the new column with either '1' or '0', depending on the value of another column in the corresponding row.

The existing column, 'Gexact', contains either "exact" or "non-specific" in each row. I want R to create the the column ('BooleanExact'), and for each row, put '0' if the value in the Gexact column reads 'exact', and put '1' if the value in the Gexact column reads 'non-specific'.

So, below is a representation of how I want it to appear:

```
Gexact       BooleanExact 
exact           0
exact           0
non-specific    1
exact           0
non-specific    1
```

Like I said, incredibly simple. I have tried using example code in answers given to similar questions, but for whatever reason (probably my utter lack of experience with R), none of it has worked. I have tried using 'for j in ___' loops etc. but it doesn't seem to be the right approach.

Any help about the code I should be using to do this, in the simplest language and method possible, would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use a comparison operator to create a logical vector and then coerce it to binary with `as.integer

```
df1$BooleanExact  <- as.integer(df1$Gexact != "exact")
df1
#        Gexact BooleanExact
#1        exact            0
#2        exact            0
#3 non-specific            1
#4        exact            0
#5 non-specific            1
```

---

The comparison operator

```
df1$Gexact != "exact"
```

returns a logical vector of TRUE/FALSE where TRUE signifies to elements that are not "exact" and FALSE to those with "exact"

Wrapping with `as.integer`, converts the TRUE to 1 and FALSE to 0

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Gexact = c("exact", "exact", "non-specific", "exact", 
"non-specific")), .Names = "Gexact", row.names = c(NA, -5L), 
 class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I'm afraid that is absolutely way over my head. I genuinely don't know what this means.

Comment: @Anna Updated the answer with some description

Comment: Ah, it's making sense, thank you. However when I test this, I seem to be getting it the wrong way around - instances of 'exact' are being assigned to 1/TRUE, rather than 0/FALSE.

Comment: @Anna What is the class of `Gexact`.  Is it `character`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean (again, I am a complete newbie to R), sorry. The contents of the Gexact column are either "exact" or "non-specific", nothing else. Also, when testing the code, all the output values in the new column seem to be 1/TRUE, regardless of the value of the Gexact column. Is this code sufficient to run through the whole table row by row, filling in the correct value?

Comment: @Anna I added the data used and the output I received

Comment: @Anna If the column is `factor` convert to `character` i.e. `as.character(df1$Gexact) != "exact"`

Comment: if it's a factor this might work : `df1$BooleanExact <- unclass(df1$Gexact)-1`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper  For that we need to know the order of the levels

Comment: yes, and it's less safe and readable, just a little bit more efficient.